# How can I resize a chrome extension popup?

Tags: html

My text is running off the screen and when I click space in the input field it moves the window right and makes the other text box run off the screen to the left. I have a DOCTYPE html and am quite new so I'm not sure what the issue is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #90ee90;
        height: 30px;
        width: 40px;
        border: 1px #90ee90;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: 40%;
        top: 5px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        outline: none;
      }
      button:hover {
        background-color: #4caf50;
      }
      button:active {
        background-color: #006400;
      }
      #totalAmountPC {
        height: 15px;
        width: 60px;
        position: relative;
        left: 55px;
        
      }
      #itemValuePC {
        height: 15px;
        width: 110px;
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        
      }
       #itemValueXbox {
        height: 15px;
        width: 110px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 110px;
        
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="totalAmountPC" type="text" placeholder="Text" />
    <input id="itemValuePC" type="text" placeholder="Text" />
    <input id="itemValueXbox" type="text" placeholder="Text" />
    
    <button id="Complete" class="Complete" onclick="onClick()">Send</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

[When I click space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kpIA.png) [What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXTLs.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I just needed to do

```
body {
width: ;
height: ;
```